# Linux temp files, cache and memory management

Tags: linux, memory, operating-systems, file-management

If a linux machine runs for a long period of time without rebooting don't the temp files, cache files and other non-permanent files become an issue (hard drive)? How does linux handle this, also how does windows handle this? What about memory (ram, and or swap if that's applicable), example if a program is running for a long period of time how is the memory handle so that there isn't an overflow or a memory leak?

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux, it's very simple for a program to arrange for a temporary file to be deleted when the program is finished with it, even if the program crashes, and this has been part of Linux since the beginning (and before: the open-delete-close pattern for dealing with temporary files has existed in most if not all Unix-like systems).  In contrast, the Windows counterpart (`FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE`) was introduced with the NT series, so it wasn't practical to use until support for the Win9x OSs was dropped.

Avoiding memory leaks is simply a matter of careful programming.